# Why do some developers assign primitive integers this way? int i = 0x0001

Tags: java, int, variable-assignment

I wonder why some developers do assign ints this way?

```
  int i = 0x0001;
```

Is there any advantage over the following line:

```
  int u = 1;
```

IMHO the first example makes the code harder to understand. What is the advantage from assigning with 0x0001?

Comment: I will usually explicitly give a number in hexadecimal form if I want future maintainers to know that this number carries some significance its its bit representation, rather than value. For example- in bitwise "hacks" or bitpacking.

Comment: For example- if I intend to use `i` to mask off all but the last bit of a number, I would use `0x0001` instead of `1`.

Comment: Thanks Dillon Davis. Can you think of a use case, where no bishifting is involved?

Comment: When you are copying from an external specification which is provided in hex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no advantage as far as the code is concerned; the `0x0001` style is not faster to parse and the resulting class files are the exact same between the two forms.

There may be a stylistic advantage, as some of the comments on your question highlight, but, stylistic advantages is in the eye of the beholder. At the end of the day it is hard to argue in favour or against 'I find this prettier'.

Answer (score 0):

Base-16 has 4 bit (`8 4 2 1`) representation making it simpler for Interpreter.

More on to it to favor 16 bit representation is sometime you need to perform bit-wise operations to set flags on and off, so in that case using Base-10 would be not a good idea.
Though there are do some security issue concerned with Base-16 representation.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate on the security bit?

Comment: I do not think it is a security issue. The values are stored equally in RAM in either case of assigning